# Snaps don't have internet access

Tags: networking, 17.10, snap

Any packages I install from the Ubuntu Software store seem to not have Internet access. I have tried multiple applications, (Steam, Spotify, Writefull)

This is the output of snap interfaces

```
Slot                       Plug
:account-control           -
:alsa                      -
:autopilot-introspection   -
:avahi-control             -
:avahi-observe             -
:bluetooth-control         -
:bluez                     -
:broadcom-asic-control     -
:browser-support           spotify,writefull
:camera                    -
:classic-support           -
:core-support              core:core-support-plug
:cups-control              -
:dcdbas-control            -
:desktop                   spotify
:desktop-legacy            -
:docker-support            -
:firewall-control          -
:framebuffer               -
:fuse-support              -
:gpg-keys                  -
:gpg-public-keys           -
:gpio-memory-control       -
:greengrass-support        -
:gsettings                 spotify,writefull
:hardware-observe          -
:hardware-random-control   -
:hardware-random-observe   -
:home                      spotify,writefull
:io-ports-control          -
:joystick                  -
:kernel-module-control     -
:kubernetes-support        -
:kvm                       -
:libvirt                   -
:locale-control            -
:log-observe               -
:lxd-support               -
:modem-manager             -
:mount-observe             -
:netlink-audit             -
:netlink-connector         -
:network                   spotify,writefull
:network-bind              -
:network-control           -
:network-manager           -
:network-observe           -
:network-setup-control     -
:network-setup-observe     -
:ofono                     -
:opengl                    spotify,writefull
:openvswitch               -
:openvswitch-support       -
:optical-drive             -
:password-manager-service  -
:physical-memory-control   -
:physical-memory-observe   -
:ppp                       -
:process-control           -
:pulseaudio                spotify,writefull
:raw-usb                   -
:removable-media           -
:screen-inhibit-control    -
:shutdown                  -
:snapd-control             -
:ssh-keys                  -
:ssh-public-keys           -
:system-observe            -
:system-trace              -
:time-control              -
:timeserver-control        -
:timezone-control          -
:tpm                       -
:uhid                      -
:unity7                    spotify,writefull
:upower-observe            -
:wayland                   -
:x11                       spotify,writefull
spotify:spotify-mpris      -
-                          spotify:mount-observe
```

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on Kernel 4.15.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know the package(s) do not have internet access? What problem or error do you have with which package?

Comment: I restored my computer. and its fixed. But every Snap installed application would complain about having no internet.

Comment: @Hego555 did you find the solution?